# Performing a convolution for smoothing a function

Tags: convolution

I want to smooth a one-dimensional oscillating function by convolving it with another function that I'll call the screening function. This screening function should have a trapezoidal form and go to zero for `Abs[x] > L`.

Can this be accomplished by performing a [Fourier transform](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Fourier.html) of the two functions, multiplying them, and then taking the [inverse Fourier transform](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InverseFourier.html) to get the convolution?

In particular, I am confused by `ListConvolve`, and whether I should do a cyclic or linear convolution, which is why I was trying to approach it via Fourier transforms.

Comment: Check http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/WindowFunctions.html first

Comment: You may add a simplified version of your functions as an example to make this question more concrete.

Comment: `ListConvolve` can perform both linear and cyclic convolution, check the documentation. You can perform a linear convolution as multiplication in the Fourier (DFT) domain, as long as the DFTs lengths are larger than the length of the final sequence. Check the answer of [this post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1172/discrete-convolution) for implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the references, I think I understand how to do it now!